# How to use scale filter in doc/examples/transcoding.c

Tags: ffmpeg

I tried to replace the `"null"` filter with the `"scale=320x180"` filter in the `doc/examples/transcoding.c` file, it only resulted into the this error message:

```
[libx264 @ 03303ee0] Input picture width (640) is greater than stride (256)
Error occurred: Generic error in an external library
```

What is wrong? Look that `init_filters` happens after `open_output_file`, the encoder is already set before it even knows the resolution of the output.

How to do this properly?

Look at this piece of code, I don't get what it's talking about, fiters ain't going to magically set the correct resolution:

```
        /* In this example, we transcode to same properties (picture size,
         * sample rate etc.). These properties can be changed for output
         * streams easily using filters */
        if (dec_ctx->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            enc_ctx->height = dec_ctx->height;
            enc_ctx->width = dec_ctx->width;
```

Found this in the ffmpeg.c itself:

```
    enc_ctx->width  = av_buffersink_get_w(ost->filter->filter);
    enc_ctx->height = av_buffersink_get_h(ost->filter->filter);
```

Comment: AFAIK, `stride` means how many bytes allocated for one scanline in the input video frame, and the error indicated it's not enough to contain any input frame. To debug this, I guess maybe you could log/print the filter description string first and check whether it is correct by running it through ffmpeg command.

Comment: I'm sure that "scale=320x180" is correct, if you are about that. I have set those values in the `enc_ctx->width` manually, and it worked.